# rescue / exeception marked as red in editor? Were Am I going wrong

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, watir

I have just started test automation project in ruby, however, am only used to java so trying to get the hang of ruby and I cant see where my syntax is going wrong.

```
rescue Watir::Exception::TimeOutException => e
```

is underlined in red, why? Unexpected keyword rescue?

```
def check(UpTimer)
  limit = 0
  begin
    @browser.alert.wait_until_present(UpTimer)
    if code
      code
    rescue Watir::Exception::TimeOutException => e
      limit += 1
      retry if limit <= 3
      #Add in Message for HTML Report?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. This makes the problem quite easy to see. Your text editor should ideally be configured to automatically set your indentation correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your rescue should be at the end of the `begin` block, since that's the block you're rescuing exceptions within. You're seeing an error because it can't rescue in the middle of the `if` block.

```
def check(up_timer)
  limit = 0
  begin
    @browser.alert.wait_until_present(up_timer)
    code if code
  rescue Watir::Exception::TimeOutException => e
    limit += 1
    retry if limit <= 3
    #Add in Message for HTML Report?
  end
end
```

Another issue in your code is the `UpTimer` variable - Ruby is seeing that as a constant instead of a variable due to your casing. That should be `up_timer`.